# Regular Expression matches words if other words exist

Tags: regex

I've been tasked with finding documents that contain certain words if other words exist in the same document. It was worded to me like this:

```
Contains word1 or word2 within the same document as word3 or word4
```

I've been messing around with if/then conditionals for regexp and I can't quite figure it out. Here is what I have so far:

```
(?(word3|word4)(word1|word2)|())
```

This doesnt seem to  work for me though. Even if the document only contains 'word2', it still matches.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you limited to use only Regex? What main language are you using?

Comment: Unless (word1 and word2) would always come before (word3 and word4), having a regex tackle this problem seems unnecessarily complex.  Are you able to do such searching with a programming language?  That way, its a simple (match1 && match2) -> document found!

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "word"? What characters are allowed in your "words"?

Comment: Basically I've written a python script that scans a 500GB share full of documents. In the script I call grep on the OS level for all the document files the python script finds. The reason I'm doing it this way is because I don't just have this one thing I need to find, I was given a huge list of these searches. By 'word' I mean a dictionary word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to avoid regular expressions here. It's quite awkward to write that using regular expressions alone, but it can be done either using a lookahead: ([Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/g7epJaHpex))

```
^(?=.*\b(word1|word2)\b).*\b(word3|word4)\b
```

Or by listing all permutations (not too difficult here, but quickly gets out of hand for more complex examples): ([Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/0gN754b1M5))

```
\b(?:word1|word2)\b.*\b(?:word3|word4)\b|\b(?:word3|word4)\b.*\b(?:word1|word2)\b
```

If your text can contain new lines, add the "dot all" modifier to the regular expression so that the dot also matches the new line character. The specific syntax for this varies from language to language, but commonly it is a flag "s" written after the regular expression delimiter. But check the documentation for the specific language you are using.

---

Instead though, I'd suggest you split the document into a collection (e.g. list or set) of words and then search the collection using ordinary code.

Comment: Very nice demonstration of the regex, as well.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I origionally wrote the script to read each file and scan it for what I need, but it was very slow. I'm dealing with thousands of files I need to scan.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a regex with the global `g` modifier set, which searches for `word1|word2` separated from `word3|word4` by any combination of characters `(.|\n)*`. The following should work:

```
(((word1|word2)(.|\n)*(word3|word4))|((word3|word4)(.|\n)*(word1|word2)))
```

If you are using Windows, you'll probably want to change `\n` for `\r\n`, due to the different handling of new line characters.

Comment: Hum, I've tried this and I can't seem to get it working with grep, egrep or grep -P.

Comment: Yeah, now I realize I forgot to add parenthesis separating the alternation in the mid of the regex

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I have misunderstood the question, but is all you want is for it to be true if `/word1|word2/ && /word3|word4/` both match?

Seems quite straightforward.  A trivial demo from the command line would be:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print "$ARGV\n" if /word1|word2/ && /word3|word4/' file1 file2 file3 ... file9999999
```

will print a list of all filenames for which that condition holds.

It will also be much faster than anything you can possibly do in Python, because Perl has pattern matching built right into the language, not bolted on as a library.  For example, Perl will optimize a bunch of alteratives into an Aho–Corasick trie data structure, which being even faster than Boyer–Moore really rips through data superfast.  I suggest building your patterns on the fly and taking advantage of the trie.

You may want to add `/s` or `/m` switches to your patterns depending on how you want to treat newlines and such.  You can also use things like `\N` and `\R` as a more portable way to cope with those.